# Adding two rows simultaneously in uitableview swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Sorry, I am very new to swift. I am trying to add two or more items in my array `animalsList` simultaneously and do an update in my tableview. How can I assign my indexPath to have two indeces? I tried to look for answers here but I can't find any.

How can I update the table view if I add more items?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var animalsList = ["dog", "cat", "pig"];

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    animalsList.append("horse");
    animalsList.append("mouse");

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: animalsList.count - 1, section: 0);
    tableView.beginUpdates();
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none);
    tableView.endUpdates();

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return animalsList.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell");
    cell.textLabel?.text = animalsList[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: just reload tableView using `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: no need to insert rows, just append your array and reload tableView

Comment: if you want to insert rows and not reload the table, you must put all index paths for the all new array elements into `insertRows(at:)`. And you don't have to put a semicolon at the end of the line)

Comment: Check my answer for insert two rows simultaneously in UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For insert two rows simultaneously in `UITableView` you can do like this.

```
@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {

    animalsList.append("horse")
    animalsList.append("mouse")

    var Arr_indexPath = [IndexPath]()

    Arr_indexPath.append(IndexPath(row: animalsList.index(of: "horse")!, section: 0))
    Arr_indexPath.append(IndexPath(row: animalsList.index(of: "mouse")!, section: 0))
    tableView.insertRows(at: Arr_indexPath, with: .none)
}
```

Comment: I think this is the exact answer to my question

Comment: Yes... @Gibs :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have connected table view delegate and datasource successfully.

```
@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    animalsList.append("horse")
    animalsList.append("mouse")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put these two lines in you viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Then you can simply just insert the items into your array and reload the tableView and it'll automatically reiterate over the array again and see the new values

```
animalsList.append('horse')
tableView.reloadData()
```