# How to update the tableview in realtime when the new value is added to array in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

I am building a chat application. I want to update the sent status once it delivered from pending state in a tableviewcell. I am getting the values from sqlite database and then displaying it in tableviewcell.

```
            if !contactDB.executeUpdate("UPDATE user_chats SET message_delivered_status = \"\(messageStatus)\", message_status = \(sendStatus) WHERE messging_user_id = \"\(userDetails!.1)\" AND message = \"\(message)\"", withArgumentsIn: nil) {
                printThis("------ Error : Message status updated ------\n\(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())\n\n\n\n")
            } else {
                printThis("One-to-one message status updated...")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Notification_To_Reload_TableView"), object: nil)
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to insert the new value in an array as well as insert row in tableview.

Comment: I want to update the existing cells state. I have used Notification center to reload the tableview but still it does not work.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148205/how-to-insert-a-uitableviewcell-at-bottom-with-animation/52148273#52148273

Comment: Fine,  but for reloading table view, you can't need to use Notification Just simply get the index of a newer added value in an array and reload only that cell in table view by index path. **Like this** https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164920/10150796

Comment: You may want to state what part you are having trouble with. Do you not get a notification from the database? Do you have trouble finding which table cell to update? Do you update the table cell, but it does not show on screen? Which problem do you have.

Comment: I am doing a chat application like whatsapp using openfire. Once message is sent it show like whatsapp from singletick to doubletick. I am updating particular column of sqlite. My requirement is such that user should be able to see from singletick to double tick in that page itself. When I come back and again if i open that viewcontroller that tableview is getting Updated.

Comment: How about you show us some of your code so we can actually see whats going on in your app?

Comment: Any help how to update the table every 10 seconds or whenever a value is appended.